# Best way to prevent certain Laravel routes/ pages from been indexed on search engine

Tags: laravel, search, search-engine

Please what's the best way to prevent certain routes from been index by search engine one a laravel app, I have got an Amin route / page, which I don't want to be indexed.

I came across an article that said I could create a middleware that sets no header to the routes I don't want to be indexed.

https://nono.ma/says/prevent-laravel-routes-from-being-indexed-on-google

Another talked about using robots, and another about using sitemap, please I need recommendations on industry best practices thank you.

Comment: `robots.txt` is perfectly fine to use

Comment: Else you can use <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow"> on your head part of HTML

Comment: you can also use this laravel package : https://github.com/spatie/laravel-robots-middleware

Comment: ok, thanks, i truly appreciate. i would settle for robots then

Comment: Google doesn't honour the "noindex" rule in robots.txt: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/block-indexing